# Android Studio: deleting com.facebook.android package from build

Tags: android

I imported an Eclipse project in Android Studio. It uses the facebook SDK. In order to import it, I had to make sure the FacebookSDK folder was in the project path. The import was successful and I was able to do a build and there were no errors. However, when I try to run the app in the simulator I get the following error:

> UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/facebook/AccessToken$SerializationProxyV1;

From my research, this points to the fact that the com.facebook.android package resides in 2 places: in my project and in the FacebookSDK module, which is a dependency. To resolve this, my research indicates that I need to remove the package from my project and leave it in the FacebookSDK module.

I tried doing this in Android Studio by deleting the package from the Build folder (build\generated\source\r\debug\com.facebook.android). However, when I rebuild the project, it regenerates the package. So I decided to delete the package from Finder outside of Android Studio. But the same thing happens when I run a rebuild.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong, or if there is some way to exclude this package from the build, other than removing it.

By the way, in order to exclude the package from the build, I tried putting this in my project's build.gradle (which I found in an answer on stackoverflow), but the error still occurred:

```
configurations {
all*.exclude group: 'com.facebook.android'
}
```

Here's my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'org.bicsi.fall2015'
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 17
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
}

configurations {
all*.exclude group: 'com.facebook.android'
}

dependencies {
compile project(':facebookSDK')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
compile files('libs/Parse-1.3.8.jar')
compile files('libs/PushIOManager.jar')
compile files('libs/crittercism_v4_3_0_sdkonly.jar')
compile files('libs/facebooksdk.jar')
compile files('libs/httpclient-4.0.1.jar')
compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
compile files('libs/stackmob-android-sdk-1.3.5.jar')
compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-3.0.5.jar')
}
```

Comment: Invalidate caches and restart.

Comment: Delete `.jar`s of whatever libs you now import via gradle dependency system.

Comment: Eugen Pechanec, that worked. Add this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
compile project(':facebookSDK')
compile files('libs/facebooksdk.jar')
```

You are using the same library (may be with different version) twice.

Remove the jar from your dependency.

Also, using Android Studio and the gradle system I suggest you removing your module locally and using

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
```

instead of     `compile project(':facebookSDK')`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to place your 'gradle.build' file, showing the dependencies part, so it would be easier to help you.

From your explanation, you are importing twice the facebook module, from the imported module and from your own build, right?

Using compile project to include module and also getting it from maven repository. Maybe something like this?

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
   compile project(':my_project_that_contains_facebook')
}
```

If thats the case, you can just do the following

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
   compile (project(':my_project_that_contains_facebook')) {
      exclude module: 'com.facebook.android'
   }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I included my gradle in the question. I see it compiling the facebooksdk project and the facebooksdk.jar. Is that the issue? I'll try what you say above.

Comment: Check what  Eugen Pechanec said, you are including the .jar and including the facebookSDK, which probably also contains the code.

You could also try to import the facebook directly from gradle, if you do not intend to use this project on eclipse anymore.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started

Comment: Yes, removing the compiling of facebooksdk.jar worked. Now I'm getting another duplicate issue, but not related to facebooksdk.